# Calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-3/2}e^{-a/bt-ct}\,\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: integration, singular-integrals

I am trying to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-3/2}e^{-a/(bt)-ct}\,\mathrm{d}t,$$
where $a,b,c$ are real constants.

I tried to use a similar approach as Gamma function but I did not manage to get anything.

I do not want the solution, just a hint for solving it.

Thank you.

EDIT: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I corrected the notation.

Comment: You may be interested by this [integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10) of the modified Bessel functions.

Comment: Is the $a/bt$ term intended as $\frac{a}{b}t$ or as $\frac{a}{bt}$? In any case the question boils down to computing an integral depending on a single parameter, so please avoid introducing unnecessary parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-3/2}e^{-a/bt-ct}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

where $f(t)=t^{-3/2}e^{-a/bt-ct}=t^{-3/2}e^{-(a/b+c)t}$

take $u=(a/b+c)t$

$$\sqrt{a/b+c}\int_{0}^{\infty} (a/b+c)^{-3/2}t^{-3/2}(a/b+c)e^{-(a/b+c)t}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

$$\sqrt{a/b+c}\int_{0}^{\infty} u^{-3/2}e^{-u}\mathrm{d}u$$
$$\sqrt{a/b+c} \times \Gamma(5/2)$$
$$\sqrt{a/b+c}\times \frac{3}{2}\times \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Is this what you were looking for? I wanted to give a hint, but then the hint would've revealed the final solution directly anyway.

**2nd Interpretation:**

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$$

where $f(t)=t^{-3/2}\exp({-\frac{a}{bt}-ct})$

Using 10.32.10 in [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10), take the following substitutions:

$$u=ct$$
$$z=2\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}$$
$$v=\frac{1}{2}$$

Then we will have:

$$\frac{c}{2 \times ({\frac{ac}{b}})^{1/4}} \times K_{1/2}(2\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b}}) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(u) \mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: I am ready to bet that the intended question was about $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}t^{-3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{a}{bt}-t\right)\,dt $$ and not about $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}t^{-3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{at}{b}-t\right)\,dt, $$ but we have to ask the OP about it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I actually added a solution for the second interpretation using a modified Bessel function as suggested by Paul Enta.

Comment: Fine job. (+1) no matter what :)

Comment: @PaulEnta: May I know how did you find that function? Did you know it beforehand? If not, how did you find it? I had never heard of such a function before. Is there a program or something that gives suggestions for this kind of problems?

Comment: Modified Bessel functions arise in the [normal product distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalProductDistribution.html), for instance, and they are pretty common objects in harmonic analysis, since they are the Fourier or Laplace transforms of simple functions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks, Jack. Then it's well-known among mathematicians. Honestly speaking, I'm a math undergrad and I have never encountered non-elementary functions, except the error function. I have some physicist friends who know these things a lot better and I always envy them. lol